# How does the frequency parameter for optimizers in pytorch-lightning work?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have a GAN that I want to move to Pytorch Lightning (more for educative purposes) and in my vanilla pytorch implementation I train the discriminator a few times more for either every step or every epoch as it otherwise falls victim to the generators quick progress.

In Lightning I've tried to do this as I've understood from the documentations with the `frequency` parameter like so:

```
def configure_optimizers(self):

...

return (
        {
            "optimizer": optimizer_generator,
            "lr_scheduler": {
                "scheduler": self.scheduler,
                "interval": "step"
            },
        },
        {"optimizer": optimizer_discriminator, 'frequency': n_extra_steps},
    )
```

However, I am doubtful that this is the correct approach as I get very good results in my vanilla pytorch approach where I just add a lop inside the training step or epoch (simplified pythonish pseudocode):

```
for epoch in epochs:
   for batch in dataloader:
       train_generator(batch)
       for step in n_extra_step:
           train_disc(batch)
```

Am I using `frequency` correctly? Is ligthning also doing this?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/4456

Comment: @alvas thanks, I found the method through that page actually after googling, according to this, what I did above should be correct, but the results show the contrary, i.e. its the same as frequency is just 1 for both. I track the loss. Do you know if it is possible to just set the optimizer to do each batch several times?

Comment: it seems I have to do it manually, but I guess then I also don't need lightning https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model/manual_optimization.html